# How to debug multiple modules at the same time in OutSystems

Tags: debugging, outsystems

After starting debugging for more modules at the same time it seems like the platform supports that, but breakpoints are working only for a single module.

Comment: Your references need to be up to date and the correct entry module needs to be selected.

Comment: @Mark Baijens, it is working for a single module, but still not for more at the same time.

Comment: If the correct entry module is selected and references are up to date then it should work. What are you debugging? Is there a popup involved?

Comment: There are two modules, e.g. UI and business logic. If I start debugging only first it works. If I start debugging only second it works. But if I start debugger for both, it works only for the last one for which I started debugging.

Comment: @gajama the platform is actually known for doing that sometimes. this problem occurs less frequently when you start debugging the first (consumer) module on your pc and the other (producer) module on another dev pc.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging can be done for multiple modules, provided it's a producer-consumer model. We can set breakpoints at the required places and can select the entry module. By performing step into operations, we can directly debug the things.